# Making a button do multiple things

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-button

What i need this code to do is that I want it so that once you click the button for the first time, it displays if it's correct and if the button is pressed a second time it displays a new question.

I have updated the code. I have tried implementing the use of counters with the help of some comments however it still does not function correctly.

```
if(view.getId()==R.id.btnEnter){
        counter++;
        if(!answerDisplayed.endsWith("?")) {

            int useranswer= Integer.parseInt(answerDisplayed.substring(5));

            if(useranswer==calculatedAnswer){
                //correct

            }else{
                //incorrect
            }

        }
        if(counter ==2) {
            randomQuestion();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So. . what doesn't work? What are the values of the relevant variables, the action you expect, and the actual action that takes place? I assume you are using a debugger so it's not like you need to guess at what's going wrong - don't make me guess either, just tell me.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are wanting without a [mcve]

Comment: so counter is initialised to 0 and when the button with id btnEnter is clicked it should add +1 to counter. What i want is a button that can be pressed two times giving different methods for each time. First which displays answer and then second which calls a function randomQuestion() which asks the user a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0;

if(view.getId() == R.id.btnEnter && counter == 0) {
    counter++;
    // do something
}else{
    randomQuestion();
}
```

at your randomQuestion(), you should decrease the counter.

```
void randomQuestion(){
 .
 .
 .
 --counter;
}
```

Comment: ty for the suggestion i have tried to do this but im still having issues. I have updated the code so its makes more sense for you to have a better picture of what im aiming the code to do.

Comment: OK, it's better to start from scratch. You use this code block at `@override onClick()` method with `switch` , right ?